# Changing Wit.ai Default Max Steps

Tags: node.js, wit.ai

For some reason I'm unable to increase the default max steps for my chat bot.

It seems that this number is now defined in lib/config.js rather than lib/wit.js like it used to be. No matter what I change the DEFAULT_MAX_STEPS constant to in my config file my bot seems to hit the same limit (5) before throwing the 'Max steps reached, stopping' error in my log when I want the bot to send a few responses/execute a few actions in a row.

I've tried linking the file the same way the example project seems to link to the wit.js and log.js files in the module via node-wit/lib

The config file:

[image]

How I've tried to link it to my index.js file:

[image]

I'm assuming I'm not referencing the config.js file properly...

Comment: where Your app located in 2nd screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write example steps of using `node-wit`

1) create and app folder, go to it and run: `npm init`

2) run `npm i --save node-wit`

3) `app.js` :

```
const {Wit, log, config} = require('node-wit');
const client = new Wit({accessToken: 'MY_TOKEN'});
```

4) from [documentation](https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit#runactions):

> runActions
>
> A higher-level method to the Wit converse API. runActions resets the
>   last turn on new messages and errors.
>
> Takes the following parameters:
>
> ```
> sessionId - a unique identifier describing the user session
> message - the text received from the user
> context - the object representing the session state
> maxSteps - (optional) the maximum number of actions to execute (defaults to 5)
> ```

so I'll add `MAX_STEPS` to example there:

```
const MAX_STEPS = 25;
const sessionId = 'some-session-id';
const context0 = {};
client
  .runActions(sessionId, 'events nearby', context0, MAX_STEPS)
  .then((context1) => {
    return client.runActions(sessionId, 'how about in London?', context1, MAX_STEPS - 1);
  })
  .then((context2) => {
    console.log('The session state is now: ' + JSON.stringify(context2));
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('Oops! Got an error: ' + e);
  });
```

Comment: To clarify, my app is set up properly (not inside the package folder) and the Wit engineers have previously recommended modifying the default max steps by modifying the package file - https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit/issues/65

Your solution worked for me though, thanks!

Comment: happy that my answer was useful (: